# My app screens looks too small for ipad 12.9"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipados

My ipad app looks good on 9.7, 10.5 inches screen, but when it comes to 12.9", the app looks too small. For example, the collection view cells, looks too small on the screen. I am trying to do two things here,

1. Increase fonts for the whole app, since iPad has regular width and regular height, I am stuck as how to increase the fonts.
2. The collection views, tableviews or other content on the screen, looks too small. Should I rewrite the code based on the screen sizes?

Comment: Leave the fonts as they are, use the readable width margins (google it), adjust your collection views based on the size of the screen, use split view controller instead of a single navigation controller. If you have specific screens you want feedback on, make new, more focused questions. This one is too broad.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez In my landing page, I have a carousel, with each view being 200*200, so what can be done here? Should I increase the sizes of these views in order for them to look good for the user? Or is there any other way of scaling the views in general?

Comment: Why not `autolayout`